# Should I flag "possible duplicate" comments linking to deleted questions as obsolete?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

Should I flag "possible duplicate" comments linking to deleted questions as obsolete?  Most users who click on them will see only a "this question was deleted by the asker/for reasons of moderation" page.  The only users who might possibly find those links useful are 10Kers and Google searchers desperate enough to copy the link into the Wayback Machine.

Supposing I do flag these comments, are the moderators likely to approve such flags?  I'm told the moderators aren't given much context for comment flags and are told not to spend much time on them, so they may not click the link to see it points to a deleted question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, go ahead and flag them. But do **NOT** flag them as obsolete. Mods will surely decline those.

Instead, flag them as **Other**, and write a message like "*This possible dup comment links to a deleted question, so it can be removed.*"

Comment: Agreed. While "obsolete" is technically correct, it doesn't give moderators enough context to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: How about links referring to OP's previous very similar/exactly same questions, which OP might have deleted themselves?